# Template compilation with MSVC, GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, clang

I've accidentally found some weird compilation difference with this code:

```
namespace test
{
    template <typename T>
    class A {
        T a;
    };
}

class B : public test::A<int>
{
    friend class A<int>;
};

int main()
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

**GCC** and **Clang** compile this just fine, but **MSVC** fails with:

```
error C3856: 'A': symbol is not a class template
error C2628: 'A' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
error C2059: syntax error: '>'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

I'm kinda confused and wonder which compiler compiles this right?

Tested with:

**MSVC**: 19.30

**GCC**: 11.2

**Clang**: 13.0.0

Comment: Compiles clean for me - https://godbolt.org/z/Ga54YM6vn

Comment: Works fine with the `/permissive-` flag for standard conformance, but doesn't work without it. I'd assume this is some quirk in MSVC's non-conformant name lookup behavior.

Comment: @user17732522 So MSVC in that case is wrong?

Comment: @toozyfuzzy MSVC intentionally is not conforming to the standard in several regards if you don't use the conformance mode (`/permissive-`). So I cannot say that it is wrong. It looks intentional.

Comment: It also compiles with `-std:c++20` in MSVC

Comment: @TedLyngmo The language flags for C++20 and higher imply `/permissive-`.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh, I had no idea. Thanks!

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks! I think that answers it, kinda =)

Comment: @toozyfuzzy Wait for something who actually knows about MSVC in detail to answer. I am just guessing based on observation with the compiler flags.